# SendGrid API - check if a recipient has opened or click the email

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I saw this API in SendGrid - https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/api_v3.html - it allows you to get all clicks and opens for your email, which is great!

But I'm just wondering whether it's possible to get whether a specific email address/recipient has opened the email?

I think that API does not have a filter by email address.

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This has no relation to PHP or laravel. Additionally, this question would probably be better for their support team (although they currently are extremely slow at responding) or their user forum, https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us.

Comment: nah.. i saw a lot of people asking similar questions and people just answer it. The reason why I wrote PHP so that knowledgable people might want to point me to a PHP Library that handles that. so it's related. :)

Comment: The "related part" is off topic. We use the webhooks and log all sendgrid events in our database.

Comment: yeah, it is related. :)